# What is the etiquette around sex in hotel beds?

Tags: hotels, etiquette

What etiquette is involved for copulation in hotel (not motel) beds?

There doesn't seem to be a lot of information about this around.

Comment: Well this is going to be a Hot Question

Comment: Buy her dinner first. Maybe flowers. Make sure she wants it.  That's about it.

Comment: Don't make too much of a [mess](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wet_and_messy_fetishism), and if you do clean up as much of it as you can and leave an enormous tip.

Comment: @Flimzy I think you're a lot more romantic than the average business traveller in a Crowne Plaza!

Comment: This is an insane question.

Comment: Actually, I'm voting as unclear. There is no personal etiquette difference between using a Hotel and your place of residence. Why Hotel and not Motel? To me, it's unclear as to what you are actually asking here.

Comment: Could I suggest that we replace the overly technical term "copulation" with the more generally understood, and still  tasteful, "sex"? It will also be better for searching.

Comment: Perhaps only just on topic, but if you want an education in hotel sex etiquette, you can do no better than to watch the hilarious Glenda Jackson movie, *A Touch of Class.* It is a 1973 British romantic comedy film which tells the story of a couple having an affair ---> https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/A_Touch_of_Class_(film)

Comment: @cgcampbell: I think this is not about etiquette differences with respect to your partner, but the other hotel guests and staff (particularly those who   wash, or don't wash, the bedding and linens). Those features typically don't exist at your own residence. I agree, though, that I don't see any particular reason why hotels should differ from motels as to the appropriate etiquette.

Comment: @NateEldredge: Presumably the question title was chosen to avoid Hot Network Questions SFW-filtering.

Comment: @CGCampbell "Why Hotel and not Motel?" That may depend on where the OP is from. In Brazil, for instance, "motel" refers to a specialised kind of hotel to which couples go to have sex.

Comment: @duplode: There may be regionally restricted (and also not so regionally restricted) assumptions and associations with what happens in motels, but the basic definition of the English word (e.g. [OED](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/motel), [MW](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/motel)) is still that it is simply a hotel whose rooms are quite directly accessible from parking lots. As such, I wouldn't distinguish (after all, there are also categories of non-motel hotels that are more prepared for short-term stays of couples).

Answer (score 49, accepted):

There is nothing wrong with having sex in hotel beds. Treat it like your own bed. Don't stain the sheets too much, since someone else has to clean it.

Think of all the people going on "romantic breaks", or honeymoons, or a wedding. Plenty of people have sex in hotel rooms.

You should put a 'Do Not Disturb' sign on the door.

Comment: '"romantic breaks", or honeymoons, or a wedding' :-) More like think about men and women spending 200 nights/year on business away from their families/friends in strange cities

Comment: @pnuts Actually, good hotels tend to have well sound-proofed rooms, I can't recall ever being seriously disturbed by other guests in my years of business travel.  Plywood partitions in backpacker hostels are another story.

Comment: @jpatokal Even partitions don't help when it's happening in your dorm :/ (shudders)

Answer (score 38):

**Close the door.** Even better, place the *Do Not Disturb* sign too, particularly during hours when house-keeping usually takes place. Plenty of maids open the door quickly otherwise.

You do not have to make the bed after, but do cleanup after yourselves if there are any fluids left outside of you or your partner(s). As a corollary, dispose of condoms yourself. Don't leave any used ones on the floor or other furniture. Maids are there to cleanup but most would rather not clean that stuff!

Do not worry too much. Hotels are often used for sex. You will make noise and you will hear others make noise. I would try to keep it down but no one expects you to be whisper-quiet.

Answer (score 25):

Generally, the only etiquette involves getting informed consent. If you are unsure how to get informed consent, I suggest following this script:

Party #1: Pardon me. I hate to bother you. Would you like to do it?

Party #2: Why yes. And it isn't any bother at all.

Party #1: Then we shall do it.

Party #2: Agreed.

Comment: Yes, that's how all my copulation requests go!

Comment: @ShantnuTiwari That's *almost* how my requests go, except  that the answer is generally "No." or sometimes "No!"

Comment: Boy was I doing it wrong all this time!

Comment: While it might have been funny to post, this **does not answer the question**,  not even a bit.